# Lost css/js after setting on gzip comression

Tags: javascript, css, apache, mod-rewrite, gzip

So I decided to try gzip on my website and finally found script fully accteptable by Google PageSpeed Insights which increase my score to 86/100 from 72/100. The only problem is that all of my gzipped jsess and cssess disappear and the website looks like there is no .css file at all. I honestly have no idea why this isn't working correctly.

Here's the code I put it in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]
RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

<FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: it seems that you specify gzip encoding for your css/js files and alter the file extensions without actually gzipping. so what's missing  might simply be a web server directive like Apache's `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript` (consult [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) for more info) and to drop the rewriting rules.

Comment: collapsar, i've tried "AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript" but in google test it does nothing.

BTW, I've found the previous script somewehere on the Internet, it's not mine though

Comment: i don't know about google test, but you have to deliver gzipped content if you advertise to do so. as far as i can see, you're not sending compressed data at the moment.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to fix it even with your advice because I'm not quite good at configuration .htaccess file. I thought there is one versatile solution for gzip comression particular files I can easilly use for my needs.

Comment: the simple versatile solution is the directive i've mentioned. i'm sorry but i have not idea why it doesn't work in your setting. you had reverted to the original file names when you tested `AddOutputFilterByType`, right ?

Comment: Ummm..., what do you mean? I put exactly the same line as this one:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript

I didn't changed anything in this.

Comment: your `Rewrite...` directives will interfere if you haven't renamed the css/js files on the server to `.css.gz/.js.gz`.

Comment: I've renamed .css and .js files to .css.gz and .js.gz but it's not working...

Comment: revert to the file extensions `.css/.js` on the server, drop all `Rewrite...` lines from your .htaccess, drop `FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">`, add `AddOutputFilter DEFLATE .css .js`.

Comment: ok, I've put this: <IfModule mod_headers.c>AddOutputFilter DEFLATE .css .js
</IfModule>

Site is working, but Google test said there is no comression at all

Comment: have you tried some _reliable_ tools which allows you to check what the transferred data really looks like, eg. [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/), a transparent client-side web proxy ?

Comment: No. How can this help me solving this issue?